# distance between two image with HuMoment distance on opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis

i would like to compute the distance between two images with Humoment on opencv.

I can calculate the distance, but the result that I find worries me when I test the program between two images does not give me zero (0) worse even its gives me a very very great result, also the big problem what the result is very random.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int basicMoment(int p, int q, Mat image)
 {
    int m_basic(0);

    for(int i(0); i < image.rows; i++ )
    {
        for(int j(0); j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            m_basic += pow(i, p) * pow(j, q) * image.at<int>( i, j );
        }
    }

    return m_basic;
 }

 int centralizeMoment(int p, int q, Mat image)
 {
    int M_centralize (0);
    int x0(0), y0(0);

    x0 = basicMoment(1, 0, image) / basicMoment(0, 0, image) ;
    y0 = basicMoment(0, 1, image) / basicMoment(0, 0, image) ;
    //cout <<"ok" <<endl;
    for(int i(0); i<image.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            M_centralize += pow((i - x0), p) * pow((j - y0), q) * image.at<int>( i, j );
        }
    }

    return M_centralize;
 }

 double invarientMoment (int p, int q, Mat image)
 {
    double M_invarient(0.0);
    double y(0.0);

    y = (((p + q )/ 2) + 1);

    centralizeMoment(p, q, image) / pow(centralizeMoment(0, 0, image), y);
 }

vector<double> moment(Mat& image)
 {
    //double* humoment = new double[7];

    vector<double> humoment(7, 0);
    humoment[0]=invarientMoment(2,0,image)+invarientMoment(0,2,image);
    humoment[1]=pow(invarientMoment(2,0,image)-invarientMoment(0,2,image),2)+4*pow(invarientMoment(1,1,image),2);
    humoment[2]=pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)-3*invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)+pow(3*invarientMoment(2,1,image)-invarientMoment(0,3,image),2);
    humoment[3]=pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)+pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image),2);
    humoment[4]=(invarientMoment(3,0,image)-3*invarientMoment(1,2,image))*(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image))*(pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)-3*pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image),2))+
               (3*invarientMoment(2,1,image)-invarientMoment(0,3,image))*(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image))*(3*pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)-pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image),2));
    humoment[5]=(invarientMoment(2,0,image)-invarientMoment(0,2,image))*(pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)-pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(3,0,image),2))+4*invarientMoment(1,1,image)*(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image))*(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image));
    humoment[6]=(3*invarientMoment(2,1,image)-invarientMoment(0,3,image))*(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image))*(pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)-3*pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image),2))-
               (invarientMoment(3,0,image)-3*invarientMoment(1,2,image))*(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image))*(3*pow(invarientMoment(3,0,image)+invarientMoment(1,2,image),2)-pow(invarientMoment(2,1,image)+invarientMoment(0,3,image),2));

     return humoment;
 }
int main() {
Mat src = imread("obj3__330.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat src3 = imread("obj3__330.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if(src.empty() or src3.empty())
        return -1;
    if( !src.data or !src3.data)
        return -1;

        //calcul de la distance avec le moment de hu
    double dist(0.0), result(0.0);
    vector<double> parm1, parm2;

    parm1 = moment(src);
    parm2 = moment(src3);

    for(int i(0); i<parm2.size(); i++)
    cout<<parm2[i]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i(0); i<parm2.size(); i++)
    cout<<parm2[i]<<endl;


    for (int i(0); i < 7; i++)
    {
        dist += ((parm2[i] - parm1[i]) * (parm2[i] - parm1[i]));
        //somval += dist;
    }

    result = sqrt(dist) / 7;
   for(int i(0); i<parm1.size(); i++)
    cout << result;
    cout <<endl;` 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the code is below"? Where?

Comment: it's just here i had problem to add it, but now it's ok